# How to calculate week number when first week of year starts in previous year

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a table named `financialweekday`, which has the following columns:

```
ID  
Year
StartDate
EndDate
WeekNo
```

`ID` is an auto-generated number, `weekno` states which week a particular date belong to. I want to update `weekno` for dates ranging an entire year starting from 29th December 2014 till 27 December 2015.

**Sample Data**

```
ID  Year        StartDate           EndDate             WeekNo
1060    2015    28/12/2014 00:00    28/12/2014 23:59    1
1061    2015    29/12/2014 00:00    29/12/2014 23:59    1
1062    2015    30/12/2014 00:00    30/12/2014 23:59    1
1063    2015    31/12/2014 00:00    31/12/2014 23:59    1
1064    2015    01/01/2015 00:00    01/01/2015 23:59    1
1065    2015    02/01/2015 00:00    02/01/2015 23:59    1
1066    2015    03/01/2015 00:00    03/01/2015 23:59    1
1067    2015    04/01/2015 00:00    04/01/2015 23:59    2
1068    2015    05/01/2015 00:00    05/01/2015 23:59    2
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: @TabAlleman: OP doesnt want the weeknumber of a date in the year but a sequence number that starts at 1 and increases for every week. How does `DATEPART` help?

Comment: It's still DATEPART() +/- SomeValue.

Comment: @TabAlleman: maybe it's too simple, but i guess OP has problems with "some value".

Comment: Well that's why I only posted my "nudge towards an answer" as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Op does wants the weeknumber of a date, but for a year that starts on December 29th 2014 and ends on December 27th 2015

Comment: @TimSchmelter I suspect that is the case (albeit I would use `DatePart(... , theDate+/-offset)`). However we really need a full definition of the week number desired.

Comment: @Richard: i find the sample data rather meaningful.

Comment: It's in the question:   Day 1 of Week 1 is 29th Dec 2014.   The last day that needs to be measured is 27th Dec 2015.

Comment: does the first week start 28th (Sunday) or 29th (Monday), your description states _year starting from 29th December_ and data shows _28/12/2014 00:00 = week 1_

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want:

```
SELECT  ID,
        [Year],
        StartDate,
        EndDate,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,'20141229',StartDate)/7+1 WeekNo
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue you're trying to solve here is when the first few days of the week are in the previous calendar year.

In your sample data, the first week of 2015 starts on a Thursday, so you want to count that entire week from the Monday/Sunday as being week 1.

As you seem to have the columns that hold the year and the relevant date to calculate the week number, you can simply compare the `Year` column against the year of the `StartDate` column, using [**DATEPART**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx). If they are different, you output 1 otherwise you take the week number that SQL Server gives you.

Example:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '20150101')
-- Outputs: 1

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '20141229')
-- Ouptuts: 53
```

So you want the second example to give you: 1

Using your sample data, you can run this to produce the required results:

```
CREATE TABLE #financialweekday
    (
      [ID] INT ,
      [Year] INT ,
      [StartDate] DATETIME ,
      [EndDate] DATETIME 
    );

INSERT  INTO #financialweekday
        ( [ID], [Year], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES  ( 1060, 2015, '20141228 00:00', '20141228 23:59'),
        ( 1061, 2015, '20141229 00:00', '20141229 23:59'),
        ( 1062, 2015, '20141230 00:00', '20141230 23:59'),
        ( 1063, 2015, '20141231 00:00', '20141231 23:59'),
        ( 1064, 2015, '20150101 00:00', '20150101 23:59'),
        ( 1065, 2015, '20150102 00:00', '20150102 23:59'),
        ( 1066, 2015, '20150103 00:00', '20150103 23:59'),
        ( 1067, 2015, '20150104 00:00', '20150104 23:59'),
        ( 1068, 2015, '20150105 00:00', '20150105 23:59');

SELECT  * ,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, StartDate) = [Year] - 1 THEN 1
             ELSE DATEPART(WEEK, StartDate)
        END AS WeekNo
FROM    #financialweekday

DROP TABLE #financialweekday
```

**Produces:**

```
ID      Year    StartDate                EndDate                    WeekNo
1060    2015    2014-12-28 00:00:00.000  2014-12-28 23:59:00.000    1
1061    2015    2014-12-29 00:00:00.000  2014-12-29 23:59:00.000    1
1062    2015    2014-12-30 00:00:00.000  2014-12-30 23:59:00.000    1
1063    2015    2014-12-31 00:00:00.000  2014-12-31 23:59:00.000    1
1064    2015    2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  2015-01-01 23:59:00.000    1
1065    2015    2015-01-02 00:00:00.000  2015-01-02 23:59:00.000    1
1066    2015    2015-01-03 00:00:00.000  2015-01-03 23:59:00.000    1
1067    2015    2015-01-04 00:00:00.000  2015-01-04 23:59:00.000    2
1068    2015    2015-01-05 00:00:00.000  2015-01-05 23:59:00.000    2
```

**NOTE:** I have formatted the dates in a proper date format: `YYYYMMDD HH:MM`, so you may need to apply some formatting if they aren't stored as datetimes (which they should be).

You can then use the same logic in an update statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #financialweekday
    (
      [ID] INT ,
      [Year] INT ,
      [StartDate] DATETIME ,
      [EndDate] DATETIME ,
      [WeekNo] INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #financialweekday
        ( [ID], [Year], [StartDate], [EndDate], WeekNo)
VALUES  ( 1060, 2015, '20141228 00:00', '20141228 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1061, 2015, '20141229 00:00', '20141229 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1062, 2015, '20141230 00:00', '20141230 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1063, 2015, '20141231 00:00', '20141231 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1064, 2015, '20150101 00:00', '20150101 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1065, 2015, '20150102 00:00', '20150102 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1066, 2015, '20150103 00:00', '20150103 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1067, 2015, '20150104 00:00', '20150104 23:59', 0 ),
        ( 1068, 2015, '20150105 00:00', '20150105 23:59', 0 );

UPDATE #financialweekday
SET WeekNo = CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, StartDate) = [Year] - 1 THEN 1
             ELSE DATEPART(WEEK, StartDate)
        END

SELECT  *
FROM    #financialweekday

DROP TABLE #financialweekday
```